# Logic based on a cell's background color

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to build something that counts cells with a background color. I used Name Manager by having a 'Name'(GetColor) with something like "=GET.CELL(38,)". In the cell I have something like =GetColor. This gives me the number of the color without any issues. The issue I am having is that, the cell doesnt the color value automatically, when the background color is changed. I have to double click into the cell and execute the formula (=GetColor) explicitly to get the number to change. This kills the purpose of having a formula. Any help would be appreciated. I am using Office 365

Comment: Changing the background color does not trigger a calculation.  There is no "good" way to   start the calculation from changing the background color.  The best is to make the UDF Volatile and routinely hit F9 to calculate.  Otherwise you can force a calculation every time the user chooses a new cell but that would cause too many calculations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a formula, please enable automatic calculations in Excel:

1."File" - “Option” - " Formulas"

2.Enable Automatic calculation.

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have the calculation option set to Automatic